# Is it possible to run an IPv6 only MPLS core?

Tags: cisco, ipv6, juniper, mpls

I am looking for information on whether it is actually possible to run an IPv6 only MPLS Core with respect to the transport labels, without the current requirement to tunnel across IPv4.

To put this into perspective, I am running a dual stack Juniper network currently and can only get IPv6 to work on MPLS when I enable IPv6 tunneling, which in essence just uses the IPv4 labels.

Is this possible currently with Juniper or Cisco?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No it's not possible today, because neither CSCO or JNPR have implemented LDP to distribute labels for IPV6 prefixes.

In my opinion people have too sentimental view on this matter, thinking IPV6-only is value in itself, it's not. You should differentiate services you offer from your control-plane used to offer those.
There is no particular reason to have dual-stack control-plane, it's just additional complexity. Personally, I'd be happy to run IPv4 + 6PE until in some far future I'll fork-lift or build new network with IPv6 + 4PE.

Running MPLS for IPv4 and native IPv6 is probably the silliest thing you could do, as you'll remove all the scaling, TE and convergence benefits you get from MPLS.

Segment Routing/SRING which uses IGP for labels instead of LDP will likely happen before LDP for IPv6 prefixes happen. So if you really for some strange reason want to have both control-planes that's your most likely source to get it soon.

Comment: And considering the fact that LDP's RFC5036 update for IPv6 support is still a draft ( http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-mpls-ldp-ipv6-09 ) it's not going to be supported tommorrow either